# find $\sum_{k=0}^{t}(-1)^k\binom{t}{k}^2$ for odd t then for even t

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

find $$\sum_{k=0}^{t}(-1)^k\binom{t}{k}^2$$ for $t=2n$ then for $t=2n+1$

I tried by expand $(1-x)^n(1-x)^n$, with no result.

**Any Help ?**

Comment: Hint: You're on the right track. Try $(1+x)^n(1-x)^n$, and remember that $\binom nk=\binom n{n-k}$.

Comment: Actually, I should have put exponents $t$ here, but never mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to exploit symmetry. Since $\binom{t}{k}=\binom{t}{t-k}$, we have:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{t}{k}^2(-1)^k = [x^t]\left[\left(\sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{t}{k}(-1)^k x^k\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{t}{t-k}x^{t-k}\right)\right]$$
hence:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{t}{k}^2(-1)^k = [x^t]\left[(1-x)^t(1+x)^t\right]=[x^t](1-x^2)^t$$
so:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{t}{k}^2(-1)^k=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}0&\text{if}&t\equiv 1\pmod{2},\\ \binom{t}{t/2}(-1)^{t/2}&\text{if}&t\equiv 0\pmod{2}.\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: thanks, this answer is what i need but can you explain more how $$ \sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{t}{k}^2(-1)^k = [x^t]\left[\left(\sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{t}{k}(-1)^k x^k\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{t}{t-k}x^{t-k}\right)\right]$$

Comment: @user130806: Try to look at the identity "in the opposite direction". What is the coefficient of $x^t$ in the product of the two series in the RHS? It is: $$\sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{t}{k}(-1)^k\binom{t}{t-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{t}{k}^2(-1)^k.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{t}\pars{-1}^{k}{t \choose k}^{2}:\ {\large ?}}$.

> \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k = 0}^{t}\pars{-1}^{k}{t \choose k}^{2}}
> =\sum_{k = 0}^{t}\pars{-1}^{k}{t \choose k}
> \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{t} \over z^{k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{t} \over z}
> \sum_{k = 0}^{t}{t \choose k}\pars{-\,{1 \over z}}^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{t} \over z}
> \bracks{1 + \pars{-\,{1 \over z}}}^{t}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\pars{-1}^{t}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 - z^{2}}^{t} \over z^{t + 1}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> =\pars{-1}^{t}\sum_{k=0}^{t}{t \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}
> \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z^{t - 2k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=\pars{-1}^{t}\sum_{k=0}^{t}{t \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}\delta_{k,t/2}
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k = 0}^{t}\pars{-1}^{k}{t \choose k}^{2}}
=\color{#c00000}{\large%
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\pars{-1}^{t/2}{t \choose t/2} & \mbox{if} & t\ \mbox{is even}
\\[2mm]
0                              &           & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}\right.}
$$