# find $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}^2$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-theorem

In the exercise I have to find the exact value of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}^2$. Now I already have seen 
[find $\sum_{k=0}^{t}(-1)^k\binom{t}{k}^2$ for odd t then for even t](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926937/find-sum-k-0t-1k-binomtk2-for-odd-t-then-for-even-t)

and I do not understand the first solution. That's why I am writing. I am kind of confused from where does this guy get this: $\sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{t}{k}^2(-1)^k = [x^t]\left[\left(\sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{t}{k}(-1)^k x^k\right)\cdot\left(\sum_{k=0}^{t}\binom{t}{t-k}x^{t-k}\right)\right]$

All I figured out myself is that I have to somehow use the fact that $(1-x^2)^n=(1-x)^n(1+x)^n$. And also all I did was to expand those two sides of an equation using binomial theorem. Now I am lost and do not know how to proceed further. Can somebody please give me a clear explanation what should I do next?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you're getting confused by the notation: By $[x^t][...]$, he meant the coefficient of $x^t$ in $[...]$ (note that the products of the sums involving $x$ gives a polynomial in $x$ of degree $2t$)

Comment: Your approach is equivalent to what he did. Now that you've expanded both sides of the identity $(1-x^2)^n=(1-x)^n(1+x)^n$, compare the coefficients of $x^n$ in both sides. The coefficient of $x^n$ in the RHS is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nk\binom n{n-k}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom nk^2$ which is precisely the sum you need. The equivalent expression for the sum (the closed form) is given by the coefficient of $x^n$ in the LHS.

Comment: Yes, I know that.  This equation means that the sum on the left (whch is the sum that I have to find) is equal to the coefficient of $x^t$ in the square brackets. But how did he figure it out? That was according to your first comment

Comment: Note that: $$\small\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom nk^2=[x^n]\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom nk\binom n{n-k}x^k x^{n-k}=[x^n]\left[\left(\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom nk x^k\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom n{n-k} x^{n-k}\right)\right]$$

Comment: Ok, I understood the part with coefficients, but now, transfering from the second equation to the third - how can I split this one sum into two sums? Is there a formula for that? I only know Vandermonde's identity that can be useful here and no other formula

Comment: I wrote it totally differently in my expansion

Comment: I reckon that you get this transition from the $(1-x^2)^n=(1-x)^n(1+x)^n$ expansion. And now do I have to compare the coefficient with my starting sum?

Comment: The sum in the second step is not the same as the product of the two sums in the third step (the latter is a polynomial of degree $2n$ whereas the former is a polynomial of degree $n$); rather, it's the coefficient of $x^n$ that is the same in both the sums.

Comment: Okay, so two questions now: 1. How do we know that coefficient of the second sum is exactly the same as the first sum. 2. How do we know that coefficient of the third sum is the same as the second?

Comment: The answer to 1 is obvious: $x^kx^{n-k}=x^n$ which is independent of $k$, so take it out of the sum, so it is $x^n$<sum>, so the coefficient of $x^n$ is our sum. For 2, note that, $$(1-x)^n(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom nkx^k\sum_{j=0}^n\binom njx^j=\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^n (-1)^k\binom nk\binom njx^{k+j}$$ Now, set $k+j=n$, what does the coefficient become then?

Comment: our first sum. But are you certain that you can write (after the first equals sign) that this sum is equal to  $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom nkx^k$ ? Why $x^k$ and why $-1^k$? I though that expansion of $(1-x)^n$ is equal to something like this: $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk (-x)^k * 1$

Comment: .... and $(-x)^k=(-1)^kx^k$

Comment: and if n is even i got the coefficient equal to 1. I think something is wrong. This is my way of getting it:

Comment: In that case, I'd advise you to edit your post to include your work so that we might find out where you went wrong.

Comment: and if n is even i got the coefficient equal to 1. I think something is wrong. This is my way of getting it: We have n even and want to get coefficient of x^n then k=n. We take the first sum and check.$(-1)^n =1$  Also $\binom nn$ is equal to 1. And in the second sum we have got $ \binom n{n-n}=1$ which give us 1 overall. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}^{2} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}{n \choose n - k} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}{n \choose k}\bracks{z^{n - k}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-z}^{k} =
\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\pars{1 - z}^{n} =
\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 - z^{2}}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{n}}\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-z^{2}}^{k} =
\bbx{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{{n \choose n/2}\pars{-1}^{n/2}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{n}\ \mbox{is}\ even
\\[2mm]
\ds{0} && otherwise
\end{array}}
\end{align}